# find out for special characters in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

My requirement is 'Following characters are not allowed for value name:

```
 [ $ & + , / : ; =? @ " < > # % { } | \ ~ ^ [ ] ` ] '
```

I have used something like this,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\"\\.&,@!?#%'$()/\\\\ \\-_<>]+$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(keyName);
```

where keyName is a String from which I am searching for presence special characters

Can anyone provide Regex for Java Pattern-Matcher?
Thank you in advance

Comment: The pattern you are using has **so** many different chars from your requirements (take `-` and `_` for instance). Why is that?

Comment: A regex is not really suited for that. Hint: `String` has `.indexOf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Instead of matching many special characters. Just  check if word has any non-alphanumeric character**. Like this:

```
  String term = "Hello-World";
  Pattern p = Pattern.Compile(".*\\W+.*");
  Matcher m = p.Matcher(term);
```

Or you can also use:

```
 String term = "Hello-World";
 Pattern p = Pattern.Compile("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
 Matcher m = p.Matcher(term);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just list the characters inside a character class (`[...]`), escaping as necessary. Since this sounds like a school assignment, I'm not going to spoon-feed it to you. Note that you may need to double-escape some characters. (The regex requires `\` to be escaped as `\\`, but to get `\\` into a regex in Java, you need to use `"\\\\"`.)

Incidentally, you seem to have a couple of characters (`[` and `]`) in your list twice.